# Test distribution normality from grouped data in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, normality-assumption, biostatistics

So, there is the question: is there any statistical methods exist to apply normality test (hypotesis check) for grouped data?
For example, take a look at data frame:

```
param,frequency
5,0.09
10,0.17
15,0.23
20,0.19
25,0.17
30,0.11
35,0.04
```

If we plot param on x, frequency on y - the points will be approximatly closely to normal distribution curve.

But classic tests in R like a Shapiro-wilk (shapiro.test), Kolmogorov-Smirnov (ks.test) can be applied only for single row series, ex:

```
row <- c(29.4, 20.2, 25.1, 24.8, 26.7, 30.8, 10.9, 21.1, 14.6, 25.4)
shapiro.test(row)
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  row
W = 0.92921, p-value = 0.4401
```

(there i accept alternative hypotesis: no significal evidance to decline equality for normal distribution).

Is there any way to apply this analytics test to grouped data? Thx.

Comment: You will need to know the overall size of the data set in order to do a statistical test.  Consider the example you gave: if it represents the summary of 25 data points, it might not be statistically significantly different from Normal, but if it represents the summary of 10^12 data points then it definitely will be ...

Comment: The standard test is a $\chi^2$ test, about which you can find abundant information here and everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, i know that no statistical tests can be adequate applied to a small row series (less 25 items). There i show only a raw example. The main question is how can i apply statistical tests for grouped data series (param-frequency)?